# Why throw an exception after a switch statement with a default case that returns?

Tags: exception, redis, switch-statement, case

The [Redis Ziplist implementation](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/3.0/src/ziplist.c#L173) has a curious convention in one of its functions - a switch statement with a `default` case followed by an external exception:

```
static unsigned int zipIntSize(unsigned char encoding) {
    switch(encoding) {
        case ZIP_INT_8B:  return 1;
        case ZIP_INT_16B: return 2;
        case ZIP_INT_24B: return 3;
        case ZIP_INT_32B: return 4;
        case ZIP_INT_64B: return 8;
        default: return 0;
    }
    assert(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Are there compilers that will fail to optimize out the assert and the ending return statement and a circumstance in which the statements would be executed? What is this coding pattern attempting to defend against?

Answer (score 0):

The "assert" keyword meant to be a debugging tool (it is disabled if NDEBUG is defined). Therefore, my guess is that the pattern above is defending against a future change in the code that will make the switch statement not to cover all the options.

Comment: Wouldn't that only make sense if the `default` case was removed?

Comment: It would. Any way, as I said it looks like the purpose of the assert is to find a future bug (as in removing the default case). I wouldn't write this assert - it doesn't make a lot of sense to me.